# How can I change the contents of grub loader?

Tags: boot, grub2, bootloader

I have Ubuntu installed alongside of Windows and in bootloader (grub) these operating systems as all of yours are with long names! How can I change the names in grub? for example I want to change the 4th one to "my fathers OS" and when I choose it in the grub it will go to the Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Try Try [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer)

To install Grub Customizer in 13.04, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:adabbas/1stppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Once installed, search for it in Dash, and click on it

[image]

Once opened, right click on the desired item that you want to rename, and then click on Rename, once done, just save and exit.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You do not edit /boot/grub/grub.cfg. It will get changed on any update to kernel or grub.

Manual way to do what grub customizer may make easy to do. But then you know what is changed.

Copy the  entries from this:

```
sudo cp -a /boot/grub/grub.cfg /boot/grub/grub.cfg.backup
gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Copy them to and edit to have only entries and names you want:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/grub.d/40_custom
```

Then do:

```
sudo update-grub
```

If new entries work, you turn off os-prober so it does not create auto entries.

In /etc/default/grub I added this:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true

Answer (score -1):

Load Ubuntu, open terminal and edit grub.cfg file:

```
 sudo nano /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

At the end of file you should find the line starting with:

```
 menuentry 'Windows...'
```

Change "Windows..." to something you need, like to "My father OS".

Store your changes and reboot system to see what happens.

Comment: I don't recommend modifying the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` at hand.